# How to fetch value from the nested json array in angular?

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I want to fetch the value from the nested json array in angular2.
I want to fetch the **client_id** from the following json array:

> {   "resources" : [ {
>
> ```
> "scope" : [ "clients.read", "clients.write" ],
> "client_id" : "tc53EZ",
> "resource_ids" : [ "none" ],
> "authorized_grant_types" : [ "client_credentials" ],
> "redirect_uri" : [ "http://ant.path.wildcard/**/passback/*", "http://test1.com" ],
> "autoapprove" : [ "true" ],
> "authorities" : [ "clients.read", "clients.write" ],
> "token_salt" : "C7NBIz",
> "allowedproviders" : [ "uaa", "ldap", "my-saml-provider" ],
> "name" : "My Client Name",
> "lastModified" : 1512452520895 } ],
> ```
>
> "startIndex" : 1,   "itemsPerPage" : 1,   "totalResults" : 1,
>   "schemas" : [ "http://cloudfoundry.org/schema/scim/oauth-clients-1.0"
>   ] }

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks & Regards

Shilpa Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

If your data will be single resources

```
    public getClientId(data) {
      let allClients: string[] = [];
      if(data && data.resources && data.resources.length > 0) {
        data.resources.forEach((d, i) => {
          allClients.push(d.client_id);
          if(data.resources.length === i + 1) {
            this.clients = allClients; // clients will be array of type number and will be declared in component
          }
        });
      } else
        return null;
    }
```

If you want all client_id from resources (resources will have multiple data) then let me know i will update answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I want all the client_id from the resources. It will be helpful if you give it in the html format also.

Comment: I updated my answer. Have a look and let me know it worked for you or not.